# Ranges in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a content type that stores two numerical values, effectively the minimum and maximum of a range.

I would like to configure the views module filter so that it will display nodes where the node range is contained within or overlaps a range specified in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Views does not allow mixed OR and AND filters. You can configure an existing filter to show all nodes where N > 30 AND N < 50 (between, excluding, 30 and 50).

If you want more complex filters, e.g. filters that have business logic, or filters that create either/or conditions, you can define them yourself, trough hook_views. This is badly documented and requires a lot of googling and reading existing filter code.